# Other than - except for

Tags: meaning, differences, expression-choice, phrase-usage

Yesterday I used the sentence:

> "I know people **except (for)** you."

and I have been told that the correct version is:

> "I know people **other than** you."

Although I have been looking at related threads, I still don't know why my first version is wrong and the second one correct. Could you please help me?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 1):

"Except for" *excludes* the person. So if you say "except for you," you are specifically excluding the "you" from the rest of the people you know.

"Other than" refers to other people but does not indicate one way or the other whether you are including or excluding the "you" in the sentence. So when you say "other than you," you are saying you know people that are not the "you" in the sentence.

Clearly, since you know the "you" person, you can't exclude him/her from the people you know. So the second sentence is correct.

Comment: To illustrate this, think of "I hate everyone except you", which makes more sense, logically.